# insmod: failed to load /vendor/lib/modules/kprobe_module.ko: Exec format error

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have cross compiled the kernel-5.4.86 version for arm64. then prepared a sample kprobe loadable module.
Attached the below error:

```
t2q:/ # insmod /vendor/lib/modules/kprobe_module.ko
insmod: failed to load /vendor/lib/modules/kprobe_module.ko: Exec format error
```

Dmesg log `dmesg | grep "kprobe_module.ko"`:

```
[ 1580.915101] defex: immutable write violation [task=sync svc 47 (/apex/com.android.adbd/bin/adbd), access to:/vendor/lib/modules/kprobe_module.ko]
```

Modinfo:

```
t2q:/ # modinfo /vendor/lib/modules/kprobe_module.ko
filename:       /vendor/lib/modules/kprobe_module.ko
license:        GPL
author:         N.Mahanty
description:    Kprobe module for t2q & t2s
srcversion:     AE7180A0589DF4FEA7AC884
depends:
name:           kprobe_module
vermagic:       5.4.86 SMP mod_unload aarch64
```

```
t2q:/ # uname -r
5.4.86-qgki-22560472-userdebug-abG996USQU4ZUIH
t2q:/ # uname -m
aarch64
```

Makefile:

```
PWD := $(shell pwd)
obj-m += kprobe_module.o

all:
        make -C /home/ganji/Mahanty/linux-5.4.86/build ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /home/ganji/Mahanty/linux-5.4.86/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Is this really a programming question? If it is not, you're in the wrong place. https://SuperUser.com is for generic computer stuff

Comment: Also, please try to format your questions so it's easier to figure out what is your question, what is log, what are the commands / output etc.

Comment: It looks like you are hitting a security feature called DEFEX in the Linux kernels for some Samsung Galaxy devices.

Comment: @IanAbbott yes you are right, i am trying in Samsung galaxy device.  can you suggest me how to overcome this? I am completely stuck from last 3days.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to overcome DEFEX. Googling how to disable it has a few hits from 2018, but I do not know if they are still relevant.